# year/month only datepicker inline

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need to create a jquery ui datepiker that only shows year and month:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var montPiker = $(".monthPicker").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
    });

    $(".monthPicker .ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();
});

 <div id="monthPicker" class="monthPicker"></div>
```

the idea is to have a month/year inline picker, but the problem I'm having is that after I change the month or year the callendar part is shown again. I have try to reapply the `.hide()` but I can't find on which event should it happend.

Anyone know, how to solve this? thanks.

Comment: Why bother with a whole datepicker then? Just use two selects, one for the month and one for the year.

Comment: just to keep things working and looking similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual problem is *after initializing the **`datepicker`**, you're hiding the calender*.  Hence the calender is showing up, whenever you change the year/month.

The best way is to do with **`CSS`**, an explicit approach.

```
.monthPicker .ui-datepicker-calendar {
display: none;
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wvjm5/)

Hope this helps.